# ng-model is not updating in select (ng-options)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to bind an array into select control and save the selected option to another variable . Please check this plunker code for whole problem and code

```
 $scope.actions = [{ name: "alert", id: 1 }, { name: "drop", id: 2 }];
    $scope.raction = $scope.actions[0]; // Keeping first element to model


  //Mark-ups///
    <select class="form-control"
     ng-model="raction" ng-options="action.name for action in actions"   ></select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/NTnxAuxwxJrIIeS4sWlM?p=preview

Comment: Works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/9zcOoBicYNDI5Q67HY3e?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq, actually i forgot mention one thing , the select control placed in a model window ($aside) and i am copying the scope . please review my code

Comment: Need to show all relevant code if you are copying the scope somehow

Comment: @dfsq,@charlietfl  plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/NTnxAuxwxJrIIeS4sWlM?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq please check my plunker.. ur code is k but i have another issue  http://plnkr.co/edit/NTnxAuxwxJrIIeS4sWlM?p=preview

Comment: You can use this binding for select: `ng-model="$parent.raction"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your scope binding. Change your code like this:

```
$scope.showit = function() {
    alert(formentityModel.$scope.raction.name);   
}
```

This was an angular-strap issue, you can read more [here](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/14)  :

> A new scope is created regardless of the scope passed in. Variables
>   assigned to the scope in the controller will be visible using the
>   $parent variable.